# Using neural nets with just one input variable (without response/feature)

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, statistics

Hi i am using following data from R library `ftnonpar`:

```
library(ftnonpar)
data(djdata) #this generates four samples, each size of 2048
data1 <- djblocks
head(djblocks)
[1] -0.11140257 -0.05594395 -0.29779225 -0.10952726 -0.03012277  0.12101243
```

As you can see, it is only vector of data, but it seems to interesting for me how can i fit those data. I want use neural nets for fitting this (especially RBF network). But in this case i do not know how to prepare data for this, because i have only one input variable. I tried create `data.frame` like this:

```
n <- seq(1,length(data1),1)
df <- as.data.frame(cbind(n,data1))
head(df)
    n    djblocks
  1 1 -0.11140257
  2 2 -0.05594395
  3 3 -0.29779225
  4 4 -0.10952726
  5 5 -0.03012277
  6 6  0.12101243
```

And my idea was to normalize n:

```
df$n <- (n - min(n))/(max(n) - min(n))
```

and then use n as feature and djblocks as response, but i think this is not the best idea. Next idea is use RNN and the ouput from RNN connect to RBF layer. This is interesting problem for me, can you somebody help me, how to prepare data for this problem ? Thank you